# Setting up passport for the first time. isAuthenticated() always returning false

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm working through a learning module on authentication and security and I'm trying to get passport up and running but I seem to be having trouble. The code included below all works as you'd expect, except that when users are redirected from the /register post route to the /secrets route, they are not authenticated, in spite of .register() having worked (otherwise the logic in the route would have redirected me back to the /register get route instead of the login page via the secrets route).

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(
 session({
   secret: "Our little secret.",
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false
 })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 username: String,
 password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const Users = new mongoose.model("Users", userSchema);
passport.serializeUser(Users.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Users.deserializeUser());

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
 console.log("Listening on port 3000.");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
 res.render("home");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
 res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
 res.render("register");
});

app.get("/secrets", (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
 if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
   res.render("secrets");
 } else {
   res.redirect("/login");
 }
});

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body.username)
 console.log(req.body.password)
 Users.register(
   { username: req.body.username },
   req.body.password,
   (error, user) => {
     if (error) {
       console.log('there was an error: ', error);
       res.redirect("/register");
     } else {
       passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {  //////////////not authenticating
         res.redirect("/secrets");
       });
     }
   }
 );
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {});
```

any help figuring out why isAuthenticaed() is returning false would be greatly appreciated. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define your local strategy :

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

here it has queried User information from the database ( Mongodb for instance) in case of successful response it will pass.